# I need to add payment integration what i needs to know?

Tags: javascript, html, web-deployment, payment

I am trying to make a website and I need to integrate payment with Razorpay or other gateways.  like this website https://gurupalacerestaurant.com/
I need to make payment things. What I need to know for integration I know HTML, CSS, JS, Bootstrap and Python. can we do python like Js in web development? Do I need to know build dynamic website building?

Comment: Choose a payment gateway you want to use and then read its documentation. Javascript is enough.

Comment: but @RameshReddy the documentation of Razorpay doesn't contain javascript it only has java python PHP etc

Comment: The very first option is for js integration https://razorpay.com/integrations/

Answer (score 1):

HTML and Javascript is usually enough - most of the payment gateways have plenty of example code for you to copy and use, choose one and check out their documentation.

The issue you may have with Razorpay is that in the docs (razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/web-integration) it says you need your own server-side and database, which you could do with node.js, but is possibly more work than you want. Other gateways (eg stripe: stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/client) allow you to process payments with only client-side JS, no server required.

Comment: Sir, I liked Razorpay more. But the Documentation doesn't have js example

Comment: Ok, you may like it more, but you are required to have a server.
If there are requirements you don't want to meet, sometimes you have to make other choices. The reason there are no js-only examples in the documentation is that you cannot have a js-only usage. For that use another provider, like Stripe.

Comment: thanks, @luke Story for the reply. i have completed the task